# The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded from form submit

Tags: javascript, wcf, web-services, extjs

I've been researching this problem for a couple days now and most of the solutions mention altering MaxReceivedMessageSize binding setting in both the app.config file as well as the web.config file.  However, my solution doesn't have an app.config file, so I'm not too sure exactly what I'm doing wrong here.

My web client is being deployed from IIS 7.  I'm trying to asynchronously submit a javascript form with xml data as a string to my WCF web service and subsequently trigger a file download on the client from there.  This is working for smaller files, but fails on larger files as the binding seems to be falling through to a default.

Using WCF tracer in my svclog I'm seeing "The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element." coming from my service.

Here is my web.config, which I know is not being applied to my request.  So, my request never even leaves my javascript client.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="customBindingNameForLargeMessages"
                  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http//localhost:32478/Services/MobileConsoleDownloadService.svc"
        binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBindingNameForLargeMessages"
        contract="Foo.Bar.MobileConsole.Services.IMobileConsoleDownloadService"
        name="" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="Foo.Bar.MobileConsole.Services.MobileConsoleDownloadService">
        <endpoint address="http:localhost:32478/Services/MobileConsoleDownloadService.svc"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBindingNameForLargeMessages"
          name="" contract="Foo.Bar.MobileConsole.Services.IMobileConsoleDownloadService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is to your "second" question

```
<services>
  <service name="Foo.Bar.MobileConsole.Services.MobileConsoleDownloadService">
    <endpoint address="services.whatever.svc"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBindingNameForLargeMessages"
      name="" contract="Foo.Bar.MobileConsole.Services.IMobileConsoleDownloadService" />
      <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: The base address can change depending on what server I'm publishing the webserver on.  For example if I decided to publish on machine name: "wServer", the service address would become http://wserver.domain.com/web/services/MobileConsoleDownloadService.svc"  Is there a way I can alter the service address from the wcf "beginrequest" event?

Comment: Which is fine, then you would only replace only the base address for the service, and all the endpoint addresses (which are relative) would stay the same. "Config Transforms" in Visual Studio are a great way to do this. That way each time you publish to a new environment, it will update the base address in the config and nothing else!

Comment: Further more, if you set up your environments the same, you can always have the base address be localhost (with port number if you would like), this way you would not need to change too much among environments.... except for when debugging because you are using 8080

Comment: Okay thanks for the help.  I'll give this a try and get back to you.

Comment: I ended up omitting the address for my endpoint binding, which auto pointed to the base relative address that I needed.  I'm giving you the answer anyways.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working.  Specified the wrong address. Now I need to figure out how to use a relative address.

Edit: I was going to create a new question for this one, but I'll see if I get any hits here first.  So lets say I have

```
http://localhost:8080/services/whatever.svc
```

is there someway I can specify

```
/services/whatever.svc
```

? 
As I deploy this on different servers.